# Cant use Android Emulator in Visual Studio with Windows 7

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, windows-7

I can't use the in-built Android Emulator in **Visual Studio** for Android when creating an Android App with **Xamarin**. It wont start and wont display anything. Also, the XAML- Previewer seems to be malfunctioning and only shows the logo of the previewer.

I installed all required software, made sure it was up to date and also enabled everything (Hyper-V, etc.) and it still wont work.

My Rig is working with **Windows 7** and has a **FX-8350 Processor**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I had a hard time finding the answer to why I couldn't use the in-built Android Emulator that comes with Xamarin on my **Windows 7** (64-Bit) machine.
The answer to why this is the case, and I hope I can help people stop wasting time finding the solution, is that you need a processor which comes with a virtualization feature. Intels i- Series upwards and also the Ryzen AMD processors implement these. Also, you need to have installed Windows 10 and enable the Hyper-V technology.
I just wanted to share this, though it seemed to be obvious, I tried a few hours finding out why I couldnt get my Emulator to work.

[This](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/live-xaml-previewer-in-xamarin-forms/) shows that it is the case for the XAML- Previewer

Comment: It seems that you have solved your issue now, please remember to mark your reply as answer, it may be beneficial to other community members who face the same issue, thanks.